# Check out this PCB design

Tags: pcb-design, altium

It's a switching mode power supply with two +24 and +12 outputs using two transformers. The primary side is shared between the two outputs but each output has its own transformer and primary side components.
This is the PCB design:
[image]
The Schematics:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you add the schematic to your question?

Comment: How much power do you want to convert ? Consider if you require a power factor correction by regulations. Currently there is none. Many labels on your schematic are not/barely identifiable. Driving MOSFETs with optocouplers is likely too slow to get satisfying results.

Comment: Check the transformer dots for V13. You can't get output. V25's is correct but V13's is not.

Comment: How can we check out anything if there is no specs or description what so ever about the circuit and the purpose of it?

Comment: Other than the transformer  'polarity' identified by @RohatKılıç it looks basically 'okay' to me, without looking deeply into loop compensation and that sort of thing. Your schematic is pretty rough- looks like some parts are off grid. Aside from being hard to follow and cosmetically ugly, that can make it harder to see something that might be wrong. Your 'Y' caps should be really emphasized as to safety rating. Layout on the feedback optos compromises creepage, is it good enough to pass your required safety agency ratings?

Comment: Is your bottom side all ground plane? Layout could be tighter, but I’ve seen much worse.

Comment: @tobalt the power for *+24volt* output is *62.5W* and for *+12volt* output is *16.24W*. I don't know what you mean by power factor correction. Driving the IC's MOSFET with optocoupler is recommended by the datasheet. (sorry for the late reply)

Comment: @Justme Thank you. I forgot to change the dots' position since I used the same footprint for both cores. I just remember how to make the transformer when I want to build it.

Comment: @Justme You can politely ask for it and I'll provide it. It's a switching power supply that has two outputs: (1) *24V-2.5A*, (2) *12V-1.25A*. The used cores are *EE28-20* and *EE25*. For the *24V* output I used *TOP247Y* and for *12V* output I used *VIPER22A* as the switching IC. What else do you need?

Comment: @winny No, I have almost everything on the bottom side. Since I want to print the board myself.

Comment: I suppose a lot of the layout remarks would depend on isolation requirements and creepage distances. Not my area of expertise, but at least the CON1 looks like it might be unsuitable given creepage. What's the pitch, is it 2.54mm or something like 3.5mm? Wider still?

Comment: Let me rephrase. Is your _top_ plane dedicated ground plane?

Comment: If the top section is for 60+ Watts then the IC (TOP24x) must have a heatsink. And I don't see any from you schematic and PCB.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, your schematic might be fine for generating a netlist, but is not really human friendly. I should be able to quickly look at a schematic and have a fair understanding of how it works - with yours i don't. There's a bit of circuit here, another bit there and so on.

What I observe with your pcb is large current loops. Do a printout of the pcb and get a highlighter and draw where the current flows. What I see in your pcb is large loops with thin tracks. The loop consists of the input capacitor, the switching device and the transformer. This loop should be as small as possible with the largest feasible tracks. This ensures the inductance and resistance is as small as possible so they don't radiate. It also means you're not wasting energy needlessly.

I also just noticed that it is mains powered. You've got optos for the galvanic isolation, but you lessen their contribution by decreasing the creepage distance. Same with the transformers. If you want to do this, then consider cutting slots in the pcb to increase the creepage distance.

ST and Power Integrations should have example layouts - have you referred to these? How does your layout compare?

By all means you can do what you want with your pcb, but with a bit more consideration you can make it a lot better. Realise that the pcb is not simply an interconnect - it is a safety component and the layout impacts on the performance.

Comment: Oh! I missed the mains part. @Momo DO NOT CHEAT WITH TRACKS UNDERNEATH THE OPTOCOUPLERS!